# Youtube Channel List Api - not returning data in order

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am trying to do a simple Youtube Subcriber app.

When i try to send the user id , the returned result doesn't match the order i sent .

This is the api i am using

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics,brandingSettings,snippet&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&id=UCqIqRzEge-Qvt4Iglx-uKdQ,UC6bA7BuUmGKPIS3wW2voNxg,UC9JgYaC76Q_eSgYM01S5J_w,UCgefQJC5UgbWJHDxBqB4qVg,UCddiUEpeqJcYeBxX1IVBKvQ,UCOmcA3f_RrH6b9NmcNa4tdg

For example , i sent the data in this order

- The Verge
- Cnet
- BfvsGf

The data returns :

- BfvsGf
- TheVerge
- Cnet

It's not in order at all. Please advice.

Comment: try orderby=published in your querystring

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Search:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), it returns a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request. By default, a search result set identifies matching `video, [channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) and playlist` resources but you ca also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource.

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search
```

include the `order` parameter, the parameter specifies the method that will be used to order resources in the API response.

You can sort list by descending order, sort from highest to lowest rating or sorted by alphabetically. The acceptable values are: `date, rating, relevance, title, videoCount, viewCount`.  The 'order' parameter will sort results based on when the resources were created.